# AndroidBar Tab on Fragments/EU4You_6

Tags: android, commonsware

How are you Mark? I have a question regarding the program you have written in the book "CommonsWare The Busy Coders Guide to Android Development".

I am talking about Fragments/EU4You_6 on Chapter 28 page 377. I want to expand this by adding an **ActionBar Tab**.

Without making any changes on your original program, what I did was that I copied EU4You.java to EU5You.java, which represents Tab2. EU4You.java will be the default Tab1.

The following are my approach:

I created a java program called **EU4Main.java**, which represents the MAIN program instead of the original EU4You. Of course, I changed the manifest to android:name="**.EU4Main**"

The EU4Main.java is where I put the ActionBar Tab. The trouble is and making me frustrated is in the TabListener setup. I have this setup ***.setTabListener(new TabListener(EU4You.class)));*** , which passes a Class. It did not work. ***Do you have any advise on this instead of passing a class?***

Also, the **onTabSelected** on the code snippets below, did not work properly. If I clicked Tab2, it will show the list for Tab2 but it will automatically returns to Tab1. It won't stay at Tab2. I don't know why?

I would appreciate of any help if you can provide a better and working approach for both **.setTabListener** and **onTabSelected**

I have also extended **FragmentActivity** to **EU4Main** or shall I just use *extends Activity instead?*

Thanks in advance.

I have included EU4Main below with incorrect and incomplete codes( I just can't make it work...)

```
public class EU4Main extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        bar.addTab(bar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Countries")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener(EU4You.class)));

        bar.addTab(bar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Artists")
                .setTabListener(new TabListener(EU5You.class)));
.
.
.
private class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {


public TabListener(Activity activity) {
             mActivity = activity;

        }


  public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction unused) {
          if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
                String packageName = "com.commonsware.android.eu4you";
                String className   = "com.commonsware.android.eu4you.EU4You";
                intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
                startActivity(intent);
else{
            Intent intent = new Intent();
                String packageName = "com.commonsware.android.eu4you";
                String className   = "com.commonsware.android.eu4you.EU5You";
                intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
                startActivity(intent);

}

        }


 public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction unused) {
          FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction xaction=fragMgr.beginTransaction();

        }
     public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                                    android.app.FragmentTransaction xaction) {
          // NO-OP
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `TabListener` has a constructor that takes an `Activity`. You are calling the constructor with a `Class`. A `Class` is not an `Activity`.

Furthermore, you are using two separate `TabListener` instances, but your code for `TabListener` does not do anything different based upon the supplied parameter.

And, you are starting activities when tabs are selected, which is not going to be especially useful.

When a `TabListener` is called with `onTabSelected()`, it needs to affect a change **to the existing UI**. Starting a whole new activity does not constitute a change to the existing UI. Rather, `TabListener` should do something like:

- execute a `FragmentTransaction`
- set a fresh `ListAdapter` in the `ListFragment` managed by the tabs
- update ordinary widgets in the current activity
- etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure out your advise.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It is working now. Thanks for the tip !!! I appreciate your help !!!